# React axios triggers bunch get requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, setinterval

I have a server and a route('/is-working') in which I render simply Yes or No, in React I do a get request with Axios every second with the use of intervals to see if its working.

Here is the code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(async () => {
        await axios.get('http://192.168.1.57/is-working')
        .then(res => {
          if (res?.status === 200) {
             // Do somthing
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          return Promise.reject(err);
        })
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
```

I want to count the number of times I get a 200 response back, when I stop hosting http://192.168.1.57/is-working and it returns an network error, until now everything is fine, but when I start hosting http://192.168.1.57/is-working again it does a bunch of get requests all together. It seems its requesting all of the ones that returned network error again.
thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That must be because you didn't defined a timeout for axios client. So, it still trying to request your endpoint, once it comes back it does all request at once
Take a look here: https://github.com/axios/axios#axioscreateconfig